# Google Sheets Add Column cells notes from Corresponding cells from other column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 columns. Want to add Column 2 values as notes for Column 1 cells.

For example:

Col 1 Values:

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
test 4
```

Col 2 Values:

```
note value 1
note value 2
note value 3
note value 4
```

Want this result:

Col 1 Values:

```
test 1 - note (note value 1)
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can get the notes from `rng2` and set them in `rng1` by using [setNotes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes).

**Note that:**

- `rng1` and `rng2` needs to be of the same dimension, in this case length.

Feel free to change the ranges (`rng1` & `rng2`) but respect the above condition.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction(){
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // change that to your sheet name
   const rng1 = "A2:A" ; // range you want to add notes
   const rng2 = "B2:B"; // range you want to get notes
   const notes = sh.getRange(rng2).getValues();
   sh.getRange(rng1).setNotes(notes);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! What about if I change something in the column rng2? how it can be updated regularly?